# Add timestamp to resource file entry

Tags: asp.net, resx

Hello it is possible to add a time stamp to the entries of resource file. It will help the translation workflow.

I want to do something like this:

```
    Name   value          note   ModDate
    key1   valueofkey1           11/11/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Use source control, Tortuase SVN, SourceSafe, TFS etc. You will know when add or changed, from who and additionaly you can add comments.